# How to include d3 on JavaScript non html file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webstorm

I am new to JS. Here is my question, in webstorm:

I created an empty JS file called `fn` under an empty project .

Then I copy the `d3.js` into the same project.

Then in the `fn`, I input:

```
var fn = "C:/temp/test.csv";

d3.csv(fn, function(e)
{
    console.log(e);
});
```

When I run it, I get:

> "Error: Cannot find module 'd3.js'"

What should I do for the correct running?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading d3.js script?

Comment: you need a html file to load the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need d3 in your project quick and dirty without loading, copy and paste the d3 source code at the top of your file. You can find a minified version of the source code here:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.13/d3.min.js

Comment: This doesn't answer how to use node in a non-html file as was asked.

Comment: Is it possible to link to a cdn as above when using d3 with node? I'm just curious.

Comment: my answer was not to link to the script, but to copy paste the contents of the script into your script.

Comment: You mean copy the entire library into a script? That seems excessive. But hey if it works...

Answer (score -1):

Instruction for this can be found on the [npm d3 page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3).

If [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) are installed on your system you could then,

```
$ npm install d3
```

Or you may want to install d3 globally,

```
$ npm install -g d3
```

You will be prompted for a root password.

Create a directory,

```
$ mkdir d3testing
```

Move into that directory,

```
$ cd d3testing
```

Create a simple javascript file called src.js,

```
$ touch src.js
```

Add content,

```
console.log("blah");
```

Run this in the terminal to check you can run basic javascript,

```
$ node src.js
```

If that is working then add require d3 to the top of your src.js

```
var d3 = require("d3");
console.log("blah");

// do something with d3 to test d3 works
var index = d3.range(10);
console.log(index);
```

On the other hand if you are not using node, you can import everything from d3 using,

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Run this in the terminal,

```
$ node src.js
```

Hopefully you will get a array list of numbers from 0 to 9